# function with mandatory and optional parameters

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

Below is my code to configure required services wherein I see error as **Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.** when executed.

Code should work if either of the parameters is passed else should throw error message.

```
param (
[Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="checks")]
[ValidateSet("srv")]
[switch]$service,
[Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="checks")]
[ValidateSet("dsk")]
[switch]$disk,
[Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="details")]
[ValidateSet("nme")]
[switch]$name)

function check_types ($service,$disk,$name) {

    if ($disk -or $service -or $name) {
      Write-Host "Argument" $name $service $disk "Provided" -ForegroundColor Green
    } else {
      Write-Host "No arguments provided" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

check_types -service srv -disk dsk -name nme
```

Comment: Yes, because you're supplying an argument to a *switch* Parameter (*type literal*). Remove any supplied values and it should work, with the exception of it falling inline with the *ParameterSet* you have declared. I.e: `check_types -service -disk`.

Comment: Why don't you just make them mandatory?

Comment: All is well-documented. Go to [About topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about?view=powershell-5.1) and read all articles named _about_Parameter*_ and _about_Functions*_.

Comment: `$name` does not share a parameter set with any of the two other parameters, so you can't pass all three at once. Remove the `ParameterSetName="..."` settings if you want to be able to pass all three at once

Comment: Thanks @AbrahamZinala for the response.

Comment: @alexzelaya I want to give an option to choose according to requirement which differ.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried removing the ```ParameterSetName``` option as suggested earlier by @AbrahamZinala and it worked out.